# Tennis match probability - is my logic incorrect?

Tags: probability

A tennis match consists of sets, until one player wins three sets. Player $A$ has a two-thirds chance of winning. Player $B$ has a one-third chance of winning. If they play a match, what is the probability of $A$ winning?

My attempt:

The minimum games for $A$ victory is $3$, and the maximum is $5$ (both win $2$, then next round is decider)

I have probability = win in three + win in four + win in five

=$\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3}+ {4\choose 1}\ \left(\frac{1}{3}\right)\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3}+{5\choose2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3}$

Which is more than $1$!

I don't understand why this is wrong though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your working: $\displaystyle \small \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3}+ {4\choose 1}\ \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3}+{5\choose2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3}$

Please see the second term. You are allowing any $1$ of the $4$ sets to be won by player B. But if there are $4$ sets, player A  cannot win *first three* sets. Same logic for the next term.

So it should be,

$\displaystyle \small \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3}+ {3\choose 1}\ \cdot \frac{1}{3} \cdot \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3}+{4\choose2}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{3}$

Comment: Ahhhh yes, that sounds very familiar. Hopefully its sticks forever now

Comment: been there... it is sometimes easy to miss it even though one knows it :)

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to realize that first to three is the same as best of five, ie. over five sets we must not lose more than two sets, so

$\dbinom50q^0p^5 + \dbinom51q^1p^4 + \dbinom53q^2p^3$

Comment: ahh, yes thanks. This was actually the way I was trying to think, since it was a binomial distribution topic probability question

Comment: Yea, in the other method there is greater chance of a mistake because you have to adjust the binomial coefficients to ensure a win in the last match.

Comment: Wait - but if the game ends after 3 matches have been won, doesn't this method include $2$ unwanted "additional matches" after? $
\dbinom50q^0p^5$ If he loses zero, he can only win $3$, not $5$.

Comment: Well, that's what may appear on the surface, but it is not so. The point is subtle, when you stop the match after winning $3-0$, you are in effect actually including **all** winning possibilities after that, eg  $3-1,3-2,.... 5-0$ Why  don't you check for any example.